# find-dired how to pass arguments?

Tags: linux, emacs, find, dired

I think that the format of this command changed since I've last used it, and now I'm not understanding what it expects of me.

I'm getting an error: `find: unknown predicate '-name=*.xml'`

The way it seem to be trying to invoke find is like this:

```
find . \( -name="*.xml" \) -ls
```

I don't understand this syntax :( Is it trying to create a nested shell? Why if so? Is it trying to create a list of arguments? Why if so?

I might just go and edit this function to remove the parenthesis, but why would anyone put them there? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis group the search terms you put together into a logical grouping so they wouldn't affect anything else afterward.  I suspect they're put there to fully encapsulate anything you might put in there so that the `-ls` (or any other option it may add due to other variable settings, etc) always executes.  Parenthesis are the highest order of parenthesis.  It is *not* trying to create a nested shell; that's why the `\`s are there: it's passing them to find itself.

But your real issue is that find needs the `-name` with a space after it, not with an `=` sign.  (ie, the argument to `-name` should be a separate argument).  It doesn't work like many of the double-dash arguments that you expect from other tools (in particular, the ones written using the GNU `getopt_long`  parsing implementation.

So, try `-name *.xml` instead.

And for an additional piece of information, here's the find man page about `()`s:

```
   ( expr )
          Force  precedence.   Since parentheses are special to the shell,
          you will normally need to quote them.  Many of the  examples  in
          this  manual  page  use  backslashes for this purpose: `\(...\)'
          instead of `(...)'.
```